# Minimizing variability in normal distribution function for every seed in Python

Tags: python, numpy, csv, scipy, operating-system

I am generating a normal distribution with a fixed `mean,variance`. For every new `seed`, I want to ensure that the saved file has the same `mean, variance` in its name. But there is some variability. I present the current and expected output.

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import numpy as np
import os
import csv

Runs = 10
Nodes = 1012
desired_mean = 50.0
desired_variance = 1.5

def function(run):
    parent_folder = str(run + 1)
    os.mkdir(parent_folder)

    np.random.seed(run)  # Set a different seed for each run

    # Generate truncated normal random numbers with specified mean and variance
    lower_bound = desired_mean - 2 * np.sqrt(desired_variance)
    upper_bound = desired_mean + 2 * np.sqrt(desired_variance)
    r = (1e-6) * truncnorm.rvs((lower_bound - desired_mean) / np.sqrt(desired_variance), (upper_bound - desired_mean) / np.sqrt(desired_variance), loc=desired_mean, scale=np.sqrt(desired_variance), size=Nodes)

    sort_r = np.sort(r)
    r1 = sort_r[::-1]

    r1 = r1.reshape(1, Nodes)

    r2 = r.copy()
    np.random.shuffle(r2.ravel()[1:])
    r2 = r2.reshape(1, Nodes)

    maximum = r2.max()
    indice1 = np.where(r2 == maximum)
    r2[indice1] = r2[0][0]
    r2[0][0] = maximum
    r2[0][Nodes-1] = maximum

    mean = np.mean(r)
    var = np.var(r)
    std = np.std(r)

    with open(os.path.join(parent_folder, rf"Inv_Radius_{Nodes}_{round(mean*1e6,1)}_{round(var*1e12,1)}ND.csv"), 'w+') as f:
        np.random.shuffle(r2[0][1:-1])
        inv_r = 1/r2
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(inv_r)


for x in range(Runs):
    function(x)
```

The current output where the saved files have differing file names

```
Inv_Radius_1012_50.0_1.2ND
Inv_Radius_1012_50.0_1.1ND
```

The expected output where all the saved files should have the file name

```
Inv_Radius_1012_50.0_1.1ND
```

Comment: Increasing the number of `Nodes` would reduce the difference between runs. However, from some quick experimentation, I think the expectation of `var` is about 1.16, so it's not clear how you would reliably end up with `1.1` in the filename.

Comment: Is the issue that you're not getting the variance you want, or that you're not getting a consistent variance?

Comment: Everything is fine for me: you are dealing with random numbers so the variance is not guaranteed to be exactly `1.1`. As said previously, having a bigger sample will cause variables to converge but this is still not a guarantee for them to be precise. In fact, AFAIK, the variance of the sample should follow a normal distribution (the central limit theorem certainly play a role in this). Having a fixed variance would cause the generated number to be easy to deterministically find based on the first number (and break RNG reliability tests). This means all of them would not be random at all.

Comment: Have you considered antithetics and/or stratified sampling?